# Calculate NETWORKDAYS.INTL in RStudio

Tags: r, excel, date

as part of my work I'm trying to calculate the business days a medical leave accounts for, given a specific month. The data I have is a column with the start date of the medical leave, another one with the end date of that medical leave, and an array containing all holidays for 2023 in my country. I was able to do it in Excel but now I want to do it in R to make it faster for each month iteration of the Database.

I'm currently using the following formula in Excel:
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(IF(AND(MONTH(A5)<MONTH(Beggining_of_month);MONTH(B5)<MONTH(Beggining_of_month));"";IF(MONTH(A5)<MONTH(Beggining_of_month);Beggining_of_month;IF(A5>=Beggining_of_month;A5;"")));IF(MONTH(B5)<MONTH(End_of_month);"";IF(MONTH(B5)=MONTH(End_of_month);B5;IF(MONTH(B5)>MONTH(End_of_month);End_of_month;"")));1;holidays_2023)

Where, A5 is the cell that contains the start date of the medical leave, B5 is the end date, the name range "Beggining_of_month" contains a single cell with the first day of June, then "End_of_month" has a single cell with the last day of June, finally holidays_2023 is the array with the holidays of the year.

In the NETWORKDAYS.INTL formula I'm using a nested if as the first argument, where i'm saying:

1. AND(MONTH(A5) < MONTH(Beggining_of_month), MONTH(B5) < MONTH(Beggining_of_month)):
   This checks if both the start date (A5) and end date (B5) are in a month earlier than the month specified in the range Beggining_of_month. If this condition is true, it means that both dates fall within a month that is before the "reference month" in range Beggining_of_month. In this case, the formula returns an empty string "".
2. IF(MONTH(A5) < MONTH(Beggining_of_month), Beggining_of_month, ...)
   If the above condition is not true, the formula checks if the start date's month is earlier than the reference month. If it is, then the formula returns the value from cell Beggining_of_month as the start date. This is used as the start date for the calculation of working days.
3. IF(A5 >= Beggining_of_month, A5, "")
   If neither of the above conditions is met, this part checks if the start date is greater than or equal to the reference month in cell $B$2. If it is, then the formula returns the start date A5. If the start date is not greater than or equal to the reference month, the formula returns an empty string "".

As the second argument I'm saying:

1. MONTH(B5) < MONTH(End_of_month):
   This condition checks if the month of the end date (B5) is earlier than the reference month specified in range End_of_month. If this condition is true, it means that the end date falls within a month that is before the "reference month" in range End_of_month. In this case, the formula returns an empty string "".
2. IF(MONTH(B5) = MONTH(End_of_month), B5, ...)
   If the above condition is not true, the formula checks if the month of the end date is the same as the reference month in cell End_of_month. If it is, then the formula returns the end date B5 as the end date for the calculation of working days.
3. IF(MONTH(B5) > MONTH(End_of_month), End_of_month, "")
   If neither of the above conditions is met, this part checks if the month of the end date is greater than the reference month in range End_of_month. If it is, then the formula returns the value from range End_of_month as the end date. This is used as the end date for the calculation of working days.

Finally the 1 means Saturdays and Sundays as weekends, and holidays_2023 as the name range for the array containing the holidays of the year.

Any ideas how to do it in RStudio?

Comment: So use the equivalent functions to achieve the logic, if not use an Excel template

Comment: I tried to but didnt work in R